# ¿Qué ocurriria si modifico un código de un lenguaje interpretado durante su ejecución?

Tags: python

Estoy ejecutando un código **Python** el cuál tarda unas horas en terminar. Después de ejecutarlo corregí un error en el código. La corrección que hice está en una linea de código que aún no fue ejecutada. Entonces, es aqui que tengo mi duda. La modificación que hice tendrá efecto en la actual ejecución?

También me gustaria saber si todos los lenguajes interpretados tienen el mismo comportamiento o cada lenguaje es diferente.

Comment: Es dependiente de la implementación.

Comment: @CandidMoe Te refieres al código en si, a la version de python, al lenguaje o a que?

Comment: El interprete que ejecuta el código es una implementación concreta del lenguaje. Cada interprete/compilador puede decidir sobre como implementar el proceso del código.

Answer (score 0):

Como ya se ha dicho en comentarios, depende de qué implementación de Python estés usando.
Si usas CPython, el intérprete más extendido, no ocurrirá nada.
CPython no corre tu código tal y como tú lo escribes.
Corre archivos *.pyc*.
Son archivos que se compilan antes de que empiece la ejecución de tu código.
Por lo tanto una vez que ha empezado a ejecutarlo, el intérprete ya no ve tus archivos *py*.